# Redirect virtual machine requests from host to localhost's client

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox

I am trying to setup a Linux Virtualbox client on a windows host. The objective is to provide a Linux environment to develop python and ruby web based applications under windows.

Virtualbox created a default NAT adapter which gave access to internet and I created a host-only adapter to access Linux http servers and /home files from Windows with samba.

I have then installed bottle.py to run a http hello world server which I can access on Windows when running the server on the IP of the host-only adapter.

Now I would like to run the server on the localhost and redirect requests made to the interface of the host-only adapter to the localhost.

How can I do that?

I googled the problem and checked some 'solutions', I've probably tried the wrong ones and while discarded the write ones. Any tip on the right direction would be helpful.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, everything was ok but the server. To fix the problem, ther server must be run on ip `0.0.0.0`